# How .NET Core configutation files work

Tags: c#, configuration, .net-core, app-config

I am migrating my .NET solution to .NET Core 2.0. How should I transform calls to ConfigurationManager like following?

```
var valueFromConfig = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someName"];
```

I searched for this, but what I've found focuses mostly on ASP.NET applications, while I want to access config files in console application and windows service application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET Core 2.0 (and in .NET Standard 2.0), unlike previous version of .NET Core\Standard, you can use good old `ConfigurationManager` class. Just install nuget package called `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`, then you can use it as usual:

```
var valueFromConfig = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someName"];
```

To add app.config - right click project, Add > New Item > Application Configuration File. Note that you might need to rebuild project after making changes to that app.config for them to have effect (to be copied to YourProjectName.dll.config file in the output).

Comment: Sounds great, I will stick to this solution, at least temporarily. So that I will not have to make loads of changes now.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration

Don't worry about that the topic is about Configuration in ASP.NET Core. It is relevant also for all kinds of applications.

At first you need to install - Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration via NuGet.

Then you need to install - Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Xml if you want to use XML as a config file. 
There is an option: you can use JSON file as a config file. In order to use it you should install - Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json

The main idea is to use ConfigurationBuilder class. 
Also you can have multiple configurations simultaneously.

Here is an example of code:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddXmlFile("appsettings.xml", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)

IConfigurationRoot configuration = builder.Build();

var setting1 = configuration["MySetting"];
```

Where XML is look like:

```
<configuration>
   <MySetting>23</MySetting>
</configuration>
```